# Simple Form Query

Tags: .net, mongodb, linq

I'm using .Net 4.5.2 and MongoDB. What I want to make is just a simple query, which gets user list from table with given user FirstName , LastName etc. I wrote;

```
   var Users = DataAccess.DbLoad<User>().Where(UserInfo =>
        ((FirstName == null || FirstName == "") || UserInfo.FirstName == FirstName) &&
        ((LastName == null || LastName == "") || UserInfo.LastName == LastName)
        ).ToList();
```

But if I write any surname and click for search, it doesn't bring any record but when I check db, I see it's there.

First Name Search Fiedl: null

Last Name Search Field: Lüle

Table: FirstName: "Ahmet", LastName: "Lüle"

How can I solve this? What is the problem?

Comment: you have to show your table data and search text in your question.Maybe your first name is not matching

Comment: "But if I write any surname and click for search, it doesn't bring any record but when I check db, I see it's there." I wrote.

Comment: "Maybe your first name is not matching " that's why I am asking you to show the data

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the && condition if you want to search in both fields As follow:-

```
  var Users = DataAccess.DbLoad<User>();
If(FirstName != null){
users=users.Where(u => u.FirstName.ToLower().Equals(FirstName.ToLower()))
}
 If(LastName != null){
users=users.Where(u => u.LastName .ToLower().Equals(LastName .ToLower()))
}
```

Comment: When I do this, it brings all data from table. It doesn't look for FirstName or LastName.